# Is there any difference between transaction hash and transaction receipt?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions

Is there any difference between transaction hash and transaction receipt ? or both are same. Whenever a transaction occurs, ethereum will reply with a hash value before the value is mined and added to a block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference between transaction hash and transaction receipt. First of all, a hash is a 32 byte hex string, where as a receipt is an object containing various information about that transaction. Moreover, as you said a transaction hash is generated right after transaction is sent to network where as a receipt is generated after it is mined. And that receipt contains information like gas used by this specific transaction, whether that transaction was a success or not, or address of the contract, if it was used for contract creation, which can only be fetched from a transaction reciept.